# How to calculate the sum of all digits?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a document with words and numbers and I have to calculate the sum of all numbers (I am still quite new).

The Error message/Traceback I get is:

```
line 12, in <module>
    final = final + i
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

My code:

```
file = open("test11.py.txt")
cnt = list()
newcnt = list()
final = 0
import re
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    num = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    if len(num)<1 : continue
    cnt.append(num)
for i in cnt:
    final = final + i
print(final)
```

Comment: Could you show what your `"test11.py.txt"` looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Change `final = final + i` to `final += sum(map(int, i))` could work.

The reason is that `num` is a **list**, so you get a **list** named `i` later whose element is string.

Comment: Just adding a little explanation because you said you're a bit new. `map(int, i)` is mapping a function over each value in the list `i` that casts (changes) the value into an integer data type. The end result is a list-like data structure that can be summed.

Comment: thanks! Y we didn´t had the map function yet

Comment: So if num would be an integer, i would also be an integer?

Comment: Yes, if `num` is an interger, `i` will. You put something into a list, you will get the same object from the list.
Suggest to double confirm `map` exist or not, as it's a built-in function of python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by Yang Liu, the biggest issue in your code resulted from not taking into account that `re.findall` returns a list of zero or more values. Your code needed to deal with lists and the fact that the elements in the list are string that had to be converted into integers.

Apart from adding the `map` call to your existing code, another approach would be to use a function to process the results of the `re.findall` call, and then streamlining your remaining code.  If your curious as to what that approach would look like, here is an example implementation.

```
import re

def do_line_sum(line):
    line_sum = 0
    for str_num in line:
        line_sum += int(str_num)
    return line_sum

file_sum = 0
for line in open("test11.py.txt"):
    file_sum += do_line_sum(re.findall(r"\d+", line))
    
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package compareTwoNumbers;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CompareNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the integer : ");
        int integer = sc.nextInt();
        
        int remainder = integer%10 + integer/10;
        //double sum = remainder;
        
        
        System.out.print(remainder);
        

    }

}
```

This is the implementation in java

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for answering your first question.